# how to include react chat app in any website like tawk.to or supportboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to include my react app(chatbot) in another react app(main website). I tried Iframes but that's not an optimal solution and now I am trying to find another method.

I loved the concepts of https://www.tawk.to/ this app and also https://board.support/ this app . to connect the support board to any website, we just have to link the main js file of the app using `<script>` tag

example:

```
<script src="[YOUR-SUPPORT-BOARD-URL]/js/min/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to integrate the react chat app into any website with a link in the script tag if possible.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There are quite a few questions already covering this: [Is it possible to load a React App into another React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334132/is-it-possible-to-load-a-react-app-into-another-react-app), [How to embed a React/Redux app in another React/Redux app without running into lifecycle issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105354/how-to-embed-a-react-redux-app-in-another-react-redux-app-without-running-into-l), [Use one React project within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930216/use-one-react-project-within-another)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use one React project within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930216/use-one-react-project-within-another)